# Pick an element from two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a two dimensional array e.g

```
0 ,11
1 ,12
2, 13
3, 14
```

so here I directly want to access element 13 only and want to compare with the value of some another element let's say x. How it could be done ?

Comment: `if (myArray[2][1] == otherVariable ) { ... }`

Comment: access by what?? index ?? if you know 13 is the value why don't you compare using `13==x`

Answer (score 1):

In the array above 13 is at index `array[2][1]`. Think of a 2 dimensional array as a normal array that contains arrays. The element 13 is in the 3rd array(index 2) in the 2d  array in this case and it's the second element in this 3rd array(index 1). Combining this you get a 2d index of `[2][1]`.
And to compare to a variable `x`, simply do `array[2][1]==x` or a`rray[2][1]<x`or `array[2][1] >x`

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want to loop through both dimensions of the array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if(array[i][j] == 13) {
            // Do something with array[i][j]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yet you only loop through `array.length`